# How to communicate between iOS app and php?

Tags: php, objective-c

What is a simple way to send a few obj-c variables to a php script, and return data. (Sample code please :))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967573/ios-communicating-with-sql-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use property list encoding:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html

Built-in in Objective-C, and very easy to use from PHP, as it's only XML...

Comment: But how do I actually send it to the server?

Comment: Use the NSURLRequest class: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html